# Golang gorilla sessions preserving form data after redirect

Tags: session, go, gorilla

From logic point of view I am trying to preserve partial form data between redirects for better user experience so user won't have to fill entire form again, just the part that was invalid.

From programing point of view I am trying to save request.PostForm data structure in gorilla session's flashes. The only thing I manage to retrieve after redirect is string representation of memory address like this [0xc2001c8b10].

Here is the part where I save flashes data after validation error (request.ParseForm() was executed before this):

```
session, _ := store.Get(request, "test")
session.AddFlash(err.Error(), "messages")
session.AddFlash(request.PostForm, "form_data")
session.Save(request, response)
http.Redirect(response, request, "/", http.StatusFound)
return
```

Also I tried registering structure with gob without effect:

```
func init() {
    gob.Register(&url.Values{})
}
```

Form values are in lower case, eg. "first_name", "last_name" if that could have any influence on this behavior.

Please keep in mind that I successfully manage to retrieve "messages" after redirect, only problem I have is with structural data.

Am I doing something wrong or is there maybe another approach to fill partial forms after redirect that I am not aware of?

Comment: I would suggest using gorilla/schema to unmarshal your form data into a struct, and then save that struct into your session (make sure to gob.Register the struct as per the gorilla/session docs). You can then pass the struct back to the template and re-populate the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're working with values of type `interface{}`, which is the generic type
and used when there can be more than one type. This is the case for gorilla's `session.Flashes()`
method as it can return arbitrary user data (whatever you put in).

You can reproduce what you're experiencing with this code ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/UhNHwlnO93)):

```
type MyData struct {
    X int
}

// Simulate Flashes() from gorilla, which returns a slice of interface{} values.
func Flashes() []interface{} {
    x := &MyData{2}

    // Convert x to type interface{}
    interfaceValue := interface{}(x)

    // Put converted x into a slice of type []interface{}
    return []interface{}{interfaceValue}
}

func main() {
    // See that [0xSOMETHING] is printed
    fmt.Println("Some data:", Flashes())
}
```

When running this program you will see output like this:

> Some data: [0xc010000000]

This is the same you're experiencing. The reason for this is that `fmt.Println` does
not step through all levels of abstraction of pointers and interfaces and stops at
a certain level unless you tell it to print everything. So if you use

```
fmt.Printf("Some data: %#v\n", Flashes())
```

you will indeed see your data:

> Some data: []interface {}{(*main.MyData)(0xc010000000)}

What you have to do to access the data is to match the resulted data for the type 
you're expecting. You have to do a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) ([example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/1bMVjnzvDF)):

```
func main() {
    value := Flashes()[0]

    v, ok := value.(*MyData)

    if ok {
        fmt.Println("Some data:", v)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Oh no, there's something else stored than expected")
    }
}
```

In the example above the first flash returned by `Flashes()` is used and asserted to be
of type `*MyData`. If it is indeed this type, then it's value is printed to the console.
Otherwise an error message (albeit not a good one) is printed to the console.
After asserting a variable of being some type, the asserted value is of the asserted
type. That is the `v` in the example above is of type `*MyType`.

Comment: I've tried with plain type copied from net/url.Values type but it doesn't work http://play.golang.org/p/3UKrl6lPnz . Does this mean I would have to create a new struct with all form fields specified in advance, and new func for converting values from request.PostForm into this new struct?

Comment: You can throw in to `AddFlash` whatever you want and it returns a slice of whatever you put in. You only have to make sure you convert it back to what you put in at the end. Nothing more to do. The reason why you receive a number in your example is that you use a pointer and `Println` does not resolve the pointer.